# My partials are rendering but nothing is showing in my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I do @html.renderaction to get the values i need to display a list in my view. The problem is that i don't get any errors and when i debugg the view it shows me the values of the model. It goes through my foreach loops and does exactly what its supposed to but nothing happens in the view.

My view:

```
 @if (Model != null)
 {<h3>här innanför1</h3>
 if (Model.Metadata.Count != 0)
 {<h3>här innanför2</h3>
    <div id="thisisthelist">
       @{ Html.RenderAction("_MetaData");}
    </div>
 }

 <h3>här utanför2</h3>
 }
       <h3>här utanför1</h3>
```

Controller method:

```
  public ActionResult _MetaData()
    {
        viewmodel = (ViewModel)Session["ViewModel"];
        if (viewmodel != null)
        {

            return PartialView(viewmodel.Metadata);
        }
        else
        {
            IList<metadata> mod = new List<metadata>();
            return PartialView(mod);
        }
    }
```

My partial:

```
 <h3>här innanfö3r</h3>

<ul>
<li>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaDataName)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaDataDescription)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LanguageCode)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaDataDateCreated)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaList)
</li>
</ul>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {<h3>här innanför4</h3>
<li>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaDataName)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaDataDescription)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LanguageCode)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MetaDataDateCreated)
 </li>

}

 <h3>här innanför5</h3>
```

Everything in my partial "renders" but nothing shows in the view. What am i doing wrong?

----- Edit ------
When i press ctrl+R in my browser so that i updates, then i shows the list as i want it. Can i force the list to update in some other way?

Comment: If your example above you are making invalid HTML. You have a loop generating `LI`s outside of a `UL`. Can you show the full partial view? The model declaration is missing.

Comment: The use of Ctrl-R to show the data sounds like a caching problem. Decorate your action with something like: `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0]` and try again.